# How to show resizing handles at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I'm trying to make a resizable `TextBox` at runtime.

I do some research and found out that I could make it resizable by simply add `0x40000` to `CreateParams`.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= 0x40000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

But it will add a thick border to the `TextBox`.

[image: TextBox with thick border]

I wanted it to be like the build-in resizing box when the user is designing the form.

[image: TextBox with resizing box]

I was thinking that since the VS has this functionality built in, there must be a way to utilize it at runtime.

I had gone through [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) and [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) and didn't seem to find anything related to it.

I had also tried to draw it manually, but since the 8 little boxes are "outside" of `TextBox`, it will be "cut off", and I can't find anything teaching me how to "draw outside of the control bound".

So somebody please be so kind and teach me how to do it.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You probably mean "at runtime". After runtime might be after the program has been closed. And you should specify if you are using winforms or WPF.

Comment: @JonasH OK, thanks! I'll go edit it.